# How to check when two check boxes both have nonempty values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit

So I'm trying to make it so that when a user clicks one of the options, nothing happens, but the second they click select an option on the other selector (whose value isn't empty), the page will instantly submit. I know I could use a submit button, but I really dislike those.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here's a small hypothetical situation:

```
 <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value=''>--- Select ---</option>";
    <option value=1>a</option>";
    <option value=2>b</option>";
    <option value=3>c</option>";
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value=''>--- Select ---</option>";
    <option value=1>a</option>";
    <option value=2>b</option>";
    <option value=3>c</option>";
</select>
```

Here's my js for it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if( $('#select').val() && $('#select2').val()) { 
    alert("aa");
    submit();
   }
});
```

Also, here's a jfiddle for convenience: https://jsfiddle.net/bcknhe36/1/

Comment: Your code only checks once, when the page is first loaded. The logic is correct, but you need to run it in an event handler when the user does something.

Comment: There's no function `submit()` in Javascript. You can use `$("#formID").submit()` to submit the form with that ID.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. Never would've caught that submit issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only checking on page load

You need to check within a change event handler after user has selected

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select,#select2').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#select').val() && $('#select2').val()) {
      alert("aa");
      $('#formID').submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Should be #select2 in the change function, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking on document ready you need to check on change. So when the drop down is changed check if both have a value.

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bcknhe36/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $( "#select,#select2" ).change(function() {
  if ($('#select').val() && $('#select2').val()) {
    alert("aa");
    submit();
  }
});

});
```